# Creating a Record of some sort in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql, dependencies, hierarchical-data

I'm trying to write a recursive function of sorts in PL/SQL.

The problem is:

So say table A has rows:

```
 {B, C},
 {C, D},
 {C, F},
 {D, E},
 {E, F}
```

Return everything that B is dependent on, directly and indirectly.

The tuple {B, C} implies that B is dependent on C, C is dependent on D and so on and so forth.
This function, when given B, would return a cursor or something that would yield: {C, D, F, E}
Notice that simple looping through and just printing values may yield duplicate results (in this case, E).

I'm rather new to PL/SQL and I can't really think of a way to do this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the table looks like this:

```
ID    PARENT_ID
---   ---------
B     C
C     D
C     F
D     E
E     F
```

Why wouldn't you use a hierarchical query like:

```
select distinct parent_id
  from (select parent_id
          from my_table
         start with ID = 'B'
               connect by nocycle id = prior parent_id
       )
 order by parent_id
```

This SQL's untested, but it should be a point in the right direction; your function could return that cursor if that's what you needed, or an array of values if not.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet. However, I'm starting to think of making a wrapper program in Java to do this for me instead...

Comment: Java?  Sigh, a hierarchy of dependencies is what is needed... +1